# Comparing cosets of two different subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroup of a group $G$ and $a$,$b$ $\in$ $G$ Then if $aH$$\subseteq$$bK$ then $b^{-1}aH$$\subseteq$$K$

I don’t know how to do this , can we just pre multiple both side by $b^{-1}$ ? Even if we can do this I am still not able to picture this step in my head.
I know some basic properties of cosets like if $aH$=$bH$ then $a^{-1}b$$\in$$H$ .

Please help to get picture of this rule.

Comment: Yes, you can "premultiply".

Answer (score 1):

I suggest working closely with the definitions. In this case,
\begin{align}
aH\subseteq bK&\iff \forall h\in H, \exists k_h\in K, \text{ such that } ah=bk_h\\
&\iff \forall h\in H, \exists k_h\in K, \text{ such that } b^{-1}ah=k_h\\
&\iff b^{-1} aH\subseteq K.
\end{align}
And you can see that actually I did nothing other than translating the definitions. It does not even matter whether $H$ and $K$ are subgroups or not.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function $f:G \to G$ by $f(x) = b^{-1} x$ for all $x$. Functions preserve subset relationships. (By this I mean that $A\subseteq B \implies g(A) \subseteq g(B)$ for any function $g$ and any sets $A$, $B$.) That's why

$$\{a h_1, a h_2, \ldots\} \subseteq \{ b k_1, b k_2, \ldots\} \implies
\{b^{-1} a h_1, b^{-1} a h_2, \ldots\} \subseteq \{ b^{-1} b k_1, b^{-1} b k_2, \ldots\}\,.$$

(Of course, $\{ b^{-1} b k_1, b^{-1} b k_2, \ldots\} = \{ k_1, k_2, \ldots\}$.)

This holds for any subsets $H$ and $K$ of $G$ - they don't have to be subgroups. In fact, we didn't even use the fact that $G$ was a group.